# Terraform : Error reason: The ARN isn't valid. A valid ARN begins with arn: and includes other information separated by colons or slashes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am attempting to integrate the `aws_wafv2_web_acl_logging_configuration` resource with the `aws_cloudwatch_log_group` resource in my Terraform configuration. However, I am encountering an error that states:

```
Error reason: The ARN isn't valid. A valid ARN begins with arn: and includes other information separated by colons or slashes
```

According to the error `aws_cloudwatch_log_group` `arn` is incorrect.

But I followed correct format according to the Terraform documentation.
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/wafv2_web_acl_logging_configuration

Anybody knows the reason for this error?
My code as below.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "test_waf_log_group" {
  name              = var.waf_log_group_name
  retention_in_days = 14

}

resource "aws_wafv2_web_acl_logging_configuration" "log_test_waf" {
  depends_on = [aws_cloudwatch_log_group.test_waf_log_group]

  log_destination_configs = [aws_cloudwatch_log_group.test_waf_log_group.arn]
  resource_arn            = aws_wafv2_web_acl.test_waf.arn

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`var.waf_log_group_name` can't be a random name. It must  must include `aws-waf-logs-` as explained in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/logging-cw-logs.html#logging-cw-logs-naming).